# Using Mutate and/or Apply Function on horse racing ratings dataframe to find average of two values

Tags: r, apply, dplyr

I am still new to the group and R.
I am working on a horse racing database.
The dataframe below displays the performance ratings achieved by seven different race
horse (rows 1 to 7). The performance ratings for each horse (column) are labelled DaH1 to DaH3,
where DaH1 is the most recent performance rating and DaH3 is the 3rd from recent performance
rating.  The dataset also has some NA values.  These are races that took place under different
conditions to todays race so are not considered as valid performances for consideration.

```
> racehorse_data
  DaH1 DaH2 DaH3
1    0  124  121
2  124  117  119
3  121  125  123
4  123  120  119
5    0  125   NA
6   NA    0    0
7  110   NA  123
```

I have generated some basic stats on the dataset such as mean and max (see code below).
I would now like to generate some calculations on the ratings of each racehorse using custom functions.
I am reading about the apply functions and mutate but am struggling to create code that
will enable me to find what I describe as the average of the best two performances over the last
three races (for each horse, row)
So for example, for horse 3, the average of the best two performances is 124, using (123+125)/2.
Where there is only 2 values for consideration due to NA values I would just evaluate the ratings two
ratings that I have.
My idea was to sort or order the rating values in each row by highest first and then take the 
average of the highest 2.  I'm trying this with Apply and Mutate but not quite getting there.
The code is below.  I'd be grateful for any help the group can prove.
Thanks

```
racehorse_data$Mean <- apply(racehorse_data,1,mean,na.rm=T)
racehorse_data$Max <- apply(racehorse_data,1,max,na.rm=T)
```

Gives:

```
  DaH1 DaH2 DaH3      Mean Max
1    0  124  121  81.66667 124
2  124  117  119 120.00000 124
3  121  125  123 123.00000 125
4  123  120  119 120.66667 123
5    0  125   NA  62.50000 125
6   NA    0    0   0.00000   0
7  110   NA  123 116.50000 123
```

Thanks
Graham

Answer (score 0):

One thing that's making your problem harder than it needs to be is the format of your data.  It's not [tidy](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html) because the names of your columns contain information about the data.  For example, the `3` in `DaH3` indiocates that the information in this column relates the last-but-third race that this particular horse took part in.  Even the row number has implied meaning - all the columns in this row relate to one horse.

If, for example, your dataset had columns, say, `Horse`, `RaceIndex` and `Rating`, where `Rating` is `1` for the most recent race, `2` for the one before that and so on, then your problem is simple: filter to include only rows with `Rating %in c(1, 2)` then take the average of `Rating` grouped by `Horse`.

The distinction may seem trivial for a simple case like this, but if you routinely make your data tidy, you will find that your analysis becomes simpler, even for more complex problems.  I promise.

So, how to answer your question in a tidy context?

```
library(tidyverse)

originalData <- tibble(
                  DaH1=c(0, 124, 121, 123, 0, NA, 110),
                  DaH2=c(124, 117, 125, 120, 125, 0, NA),
                  DaH3=c(121, 119, 123, 119, NA, 0, 123)
                )

# Tidy the data
tidyData <- originalData %>% 
              pivot_longer(
                values_to="Rating", 
                cols=c(DaH1, DaH2, DaH3), 
                names_prefix="DaH", 
                names_to="RaceIdx"
              ) %>% 
              mutate(
                RaceIdx=as.numeric(RaceIdx), 
                Horse=rep(1:7, each=3)
              )
# Check it looks right
tidyData %>% head()
# Answer the question
tidyData %>% 
  filter(RaceIdx < 3) %>% 
  group_by(Horse) %>% 
  summarise(Rating=mean(Rating, rm.na=TRUE))
```

Giving

```
# A tibble: 7 x 2
  Horse Rating
  <int>  <dbl>
1     1   62  
2     2  120. 
3     3  123  
4     4  122. 
5     5   62.5
6     6   NA  
7     7   NA
```

** Edit **

Or, to answer the question you actually asked (sorry!)

```
tidyData %>%
  group_by(Horse) %>% 
  arrange(desc(Rating)) %>% 
  mutate(Rank=row_number()) %>% 
  filter(Rank < 3) %>% 
  summarise(Rating=mean(Rating))
```

Giving

```
# A tibble: 7 x 2
  Horse Rating
  <int>  <dbl>
1     1  122. 
2     2  122. 
3     3  124  
4     4  122. 
5     5   62.5
6     6    0  
7     7  116.
```

Comment: But this doesn't take the average of the best two performances over the last three races? Sorry, just saw the edit :)

Comment: @DominikS.Meier No problem.  Less haste more speed! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with `dplyr`. I also use `pivot_longer` to bring you data into a long format. Then I group the data by horse, keep only the top 2 rating values by horse and take the mean of these two ratings by horse:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  mutate(horse = 1:nrow(.)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(DaH1:DaH3, values_to = "rating") %>% 
  group_by(horse) %>% 
  top_n(2, wt =rating) %>% 
  summarise(mean_rating = mean(rating))

# A tibble: 7 x 2
  horse mean_rating
  <int>      <dbl>
1     1      122. 
2     2      122. 
3     3      124  
4     4      122. 
5     5       62.5
6     6        0  
7     7      116.
```

*Data*

```
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~DaH1,~DaH2,~DaH3,
      0  ,124  ,121,
    124 , 117 , 119,
    121 , 125 , 123,
    123 , 120 , 119,
      0  ,125   ,NA,
     NA ,   0   , 0,
    110 ,  NA , 123,
  )
```

Comment: HI. Thanks for all the help. I'm getting my head around the coding and making steady progress with the project.  The project is to manipulate and perform calculations on my horse racing database to speed up a large amount of daily manual calculations that I am currently doing.  I hope the following question is not inappropriate for this forum as I do not know what the protocol is:  Do any of the programmers on the forum provide paid for services to undertake projects in R? If I am not able achieve my goals myself then I would be looking for a programmer to complete the project.  Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

```
racehorse_data <- data.frame(DaH1 = c(0, 124, 121, 123, 0, NA, 110),
                   DaH2 = c(123, 117, 125, 120, 125, 0, NA),
                   DaH3 = c(121, 119, 123, 119, NA, 0, 123))
```

I would start with creating function to calculate 2nd best result (since we can find the best one with max)

```
find_second <- function(x){
  n <- length(x)
  sort(x, partial=n-1, na.last = FALSE)[n-1]
}
```

And now we can create 2 columns with best and second best result and calculate mean of those 2 values:

```
racehorse_data$second_best <- apply(racehorse_data,1, find_second)
racehorse_data$Max <- apply(racehorse_data,1,max,na.rm=T)
racehorse_data$Mean <- rowMeans(cbind(racehorse_data$second_best, racehorse_data$Max), na.rm = TRUE)
```

result:

```
> racehorse_data
  DaH1 DaH2 DaH3 second_best Max  Mean
1    0  123  121         121 123 122.0
2  124  117  119         119 124 121.5
3  121  125  123         123 125 124.0
4  123  120  119         120 123 121.5
5    0  125   NA           0 125  62.5
6   NA    0    0           0   0   0.0
7  110   NA  123         110 123 116.5
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  This worked for the problem 3 ratings for each horse.  If I want to run the find_second function for a greater number of racehorse ratings, such as 6, then I get an error.